# Many to many relationship to itself in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many

Using PostgreSQL, I have a table that should have a many to many relationship to itself. The table is called `tools` and I'm doing the many to many with a secondary table, called `integrations`, that has two fields, `tool_a_id` and `tool_b_id`.

Is there a better way? The problem with this is that whenever I want to find all integrations I need to check for both `tool_a` and `tool_b`, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM integrations
WHERE tool_a_id = x AND tool_b_id = x
```

or when I want to select all tools that integrate with another one, I have to do:

```
SELECT "tools".* FROM tools, integrations
WHERE ((tools.id = integrations.tool_a_id AND integrations.tool_b_id = x) 
   OR (tools.id = integrations.tool_b_id AND integrations.tool_a_id = x))
```

This for example, doesn't allow to easily define integrations as a relationship in Rails as Rails expects one and only one foreign key to match. Is there a better way? It feels inelegant. I don't mind being stuck with PostgreSQL.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the question is poorly built. How about a bit of code?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I really don't know what code you want, I'm asking a database design question. I added a couple of queries if you think that's useful, but my question is conceptual.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's the way we've learned it from RDBMS books. ;)

But in your SQL example, you're not defining the objects correctly. I think what you might be looking for is something more like this (with the same database schema):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tools t1 JOIN integrations i ON (t1.id = i.tool_a_id)
       JOIN tools t2 ON (t2.id = i.tool_b_id)
WHERE t2.id = x
```

That is more elegant, as it labels **t1** as the list of tools to pick from and **t2** as the list from which I will select the one tool I want to know which are the ones integrated to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Martín. I am not sending queries by hand every time. I'm using an ORM so I'm not sure what effect it'll have to alias a table like you did. I try to go against the ORM only as much as necessary, as doing more will make it misbehave.

Comment: The aliases here are just to shorten the SQL, you can ignore them. The main idea is to use the tools table twice, once for the selected tool and another time for the tools it references.